# How to pass parameter to sql file with DatabricksSqlOperator in Airflow?

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

The sample.sql file

```
INSERT INTO db.table
VALUES (
    '{{ ds }}',
    '${item1}',
    '{item2}'
)
;
```

The airflow operator

```
        task = DatabricksSqlOperator(
            task_id=task_id,
            sql_endpoint_name="my-serverless-endpoint",
            sql="sample.sql",
            parameters={
                "item1": "abc",
                "item2": "xyz"
            },
        )
```

The result
db.table

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-05 | ${item1} | {item2} |

The marcro {{ ds }} works just fine. But I can't figure out how to get other parameter to work
DatabricksSqlOperator is extending the SQLExecuteQueryOperator
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/providers/databricks/operators/databricks_sql.py

I tried

1. '${item1}',
2. '{item1}
3. '{params["item1"]}',
4. '{param.item1}',
5. '{parameters["item1"]}',
6. '{parameters.item1}',

Hoping to get

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-05 | abc | xyz |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use it as Jinja Template : {{ params.item1 }}

DatabricksSqlOperator inherited from SQLExecuteQueryOperator that parse it that way.